# Serving compiled jade with express when browser requests "element.html"

Tags: node.js, express, pug, polymer

my layout.jade contains link imports of regular html polymer elements, like such:

```
link(rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html")
```

I was inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robdodson/8047805) to write my polymer elements in jade, but now I'm not sure how to serve them when the browser (through the page served from index.jade) requests "paper-tabs.html".

I'm basically trying to find out how to serve that jade element to the jade layout file? I don't imagine it's possible to do

```
link(rel="import" href="/foo-element.jade")
```

Has anybody gotten this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement it yourself by listening for requests to ".html" files in the relevant components folder and using the "jade" npm module to compile the template and serve it, or you could just use an [npm module somebody already wrote](https://github.com/runk/connect-jade-static) to do the same (it's a little more complex than it sounds).